# Gear Reduction -> Gear Multiplication. Will it work?

Tags: classical-mechanics

I've seen a few [cool](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ApqfqiFTO4E) [videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QwXK4e4uqXY) where there is series of gears such that the first gear spins extremely fast while the last gear doesn't appear to spin at all.

I think it would be cool to build a machine like this, but then at the end continue the machine with gear multiplication, such that the first gear spins really fast, the center gear doesn't appear to be moving at all, and then the last gear is spinning as fast as the first gear again.

Can this be accomplished?

If so, what is the highest ratio that one could reasonably expect to have at the center, given material limitations?

If not, why doesn't it work? Is there some issue with energy / force loss?

Comment: Welcome *New contributor* JoshuaD! This seems (to me) to be more of an engineering question than a theoretical or experimental physics question. I've voted to close it for that reason. Here's the meta post regarding engineering questions:  [Are engineering questions appropriate for this site?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4535/9887)

Answer (score 1):

The gear equations  is:

$$\omega_{\text{out}}=i\,\omega_{\text{in}}=\frac{Z_\text{in}}{Z_\text{out}}\,\omega_{\text{in}}\tag 1$$

where i is the gear ratio and Z are the number of the gear teeth.

with equation (1) you can drive the transmistion between $\omega_4$ and $\omega_1$

with:

$$\omega_2=\frac{Z_1}{Z_2}\,\omega_1$$

$$\omega_3=\frac{Z_2}{Z_3}\,\omega_2$$

$$\omega_4=\frac{Z_3}{Z_4}\,\omega_3$$

you obtain:

$$\omega_4=\frac{Z_3}{Z_4}\,\frac{Z_2}{Z_3}\,\frac{Z_1}{Z_2}\,\omega_1$$

your requirement $\omega_4=\omega_1$ thus:

$$Z_4=Z_1$$

and for $\omega_3 \ll \omega_2\ll \omega_1$ thus

$$Z_3 \gg Z_2\gg Z_1$$